# How to reset the identity column in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I need to reset my identity field parametrically in MVC.net. I am using Linq and Entity Framework.

**Reason:** I am inserting thousands of records in my table by importing. I am importing records again after some period of time, so my id field value increasing so much

For ex. In 100000000 so my field data type is Big int but it is not sufficient for my this value. So I need to reset my identity field.

Comment: If you insert alot of values, why did you choose a data type that is expected to cause you problems? A guid for example will not suffer from this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that `bigint` isn't sufficient? If you're inserting 1000000000000 rows per day, it will still take 25000 years to exhaust the range of `bigint`. (assuming you started at 1. If you started at the lowest possible value, it'll be 50000 years)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I  know  this  things   but  any  how   its  client  req.  so i  need  to  do

Answer (score 8):

Hi  I  have  searched  and  found  answer  for  my  related  question.

that  is  the  query   in  c# with  mvc3  and  entity framework

```
 db.ExecuteStoreCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('BibContents',RESEED,1);");
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Be aware that this now *might* lead to duplicate values in your column! Be careful when *fiddling* with the `IDENTITY` values.....

Comment: I would be wary of this, to execute DBCC CHECKIDENT the connecting account needs to own the table, or be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role.

It is highly likely you are running your application with database privileges that are way too high if you have any concern for security.

Comment: before that I would call a truncate (context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]"); ) or delete (context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [TableName]"); ) to wipe out old values so you won't have any duplicates.